# bash script running from cronjob command not found

Tags: cron, shell

my crontab is as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
01 04 * * * root /home/sphinx_scripts/daily_update_index.sh
```

daily_update_index.sh is as follows:

```
indexer  --rotate xxx
```

now if I run /home/sphinx_scripts/daily_update_index.sh from anywhere(as root), it works fine.   But I get emails daily from cron job saying "command indexer is not found".  the full path of the indexer is /usr/loca/bin/indexer.  Why would I get such an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that indexer is not on the path. You say it is /usr/local/bin/indexer and you have `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
To fix this I would put the whole path to indexer in daily_update_index.sh or add `/usr/local/bin` to the path in daily_update_index.sh

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an AWS EC2 instance and for me the issue was that I used pscp to transfer my .sh file from my Windows 10 machine, and the file's line endings were incompatible. So I used `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` and then used dos2unix to convert the file to the correct format.