# Script runs manually, Not working in Cron

Tags: shell, sqlcmd

I can able to run my script manually all the commands works fine, When i run my script in cron its not working throwing a error.

Script

```
#! /bin/sh -x
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

/bin/sh /etc/profile

increment=0

if [ $increment != 0 ]
then

sqlcmd -h-1 -S ***** -U sa -P '*****' -d abc -i input.sql -W -w 1024 -s"," >> output.csv

else

echo "header printed!"

sqlcmd -S ***** -U sa -P '******' -d abc -i input.sql -W -w 1024 -s"," >> output.csv

fi

increment+=1

sed -e 's/-,//g;s/-//g;s/,,//g;/^$/d' output.csv > Uploadstatus.csv

rm -rf output.csv
```

Cron entry

```
2 * * * * /script.sh
```

Error:

```
+ PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ /bin/sh /etc/profile
+ increment=0
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'header printed!'
header printed!
+ sqlcmd -S *** -U sa -P '*****' -d abc -i input.sql -W -w 1024 -s,
/script.sh: line 16: **sqlcmd: command not found**
+ increment+=1
+ sed -e 's/-,//g;s/-//g;s/,,//g;/^$/d' output.csv
+ rm -rf output.csv
```

Comment: Add the full path for sqlcmd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script running from cronjob command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912872/bash-script-running-from-cronjob-command-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the clue: `/script.sh: line 16: **sqlcmd: command not found**`

Prefix sqlcmd with the path and you should be OK.

For example:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -h-1 -S ...
```

You can find the path to your copy of sqlcmd with:

```
which sqlcmd
```

Answer (score 0):

The **script.sh** file should have the execute permission for the user under which the cron tab has been set. Try the bellow,

> chmod 755 script.sh